# Retornar 403.7 en .net framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Estoy queriendo forzar el retorno del statusCode 403.7 en un controlador de .net pero no encuentro la manera.
Usando "return new  HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);" solo puedo devolver el 403.0
Existe una manera de hacerlo?
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el método `return StatusCode(xxxx);` para devolver un valor que no esté dentro de las constantes definidas en `System.Net.HttpStatusCode`